# How to query sqlalchemy object with "IN" in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model like

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=True, nullable=False)
    character = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
```

I also have a list of characters `chars = [char1, char2, ...]`

In SQL I can say

```
select * from User
where character in ('char1', 'char2',...)
```

How can I write this is python?

Based on similar questions asked here I tried:

```
foo = User.query.filter_by(User.character.in_(chars)).all()
```

but this gives me the error `filter_by() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
session.query(User).filter(User. character.in_(chars)).all()
```

Comment: This worked thank you! Why is that so, what is the difference between filter and filter_by? (I will accept when it allows me to)

Comment: Thanks, please read my comment again, I said I will accept I already tried but it said I had to wait because the question wasn't old enough!

Comment: Sorry missed that part.